# Is there a package that I can use in order to get rules for a target outcome in R

Tags: r, clustering, optimization, association-rules

For example In this given data set I would like to get the best values of each variable that will yield a pre-set value of "percentage" :
for example I need that the value of "percentage" will be >=0.7 
so in this case the outcome should be something like:
 `birds >=5, 2 =< wolfs , 2<=snakes <=4`

```
dat <- read.table(text = "birds    wolfs     snakes  percentage
3         8          7         0.50
1         2          3         0.33
5         1          1         0.66
6         3          2         0.80
5         2          4         0.74",header = TRUE)
```

I can't use decision trees as I have a large data frame and I can't see all tree correctly.
I tried the arules package as  but it required that all variables will be factors and I have mixed dataset of factor,logical and continuous variables.Also I need "percentage" variable to be the only one that I would like to optimize.
Here is my code :

```
library(arules)
    dat$birds<-as.factor(dat$birds)
    dat$wolfs<-as.factor(dat$wolfs)
    dat$snakes<-as.factor(dat$snakes)
    dat$percentage<-as.factor(dat$percentage)
    rules<-apriori(dat, parameter = list(minlen=2, supp=0.005, conf=0.8))
    rules.sorted <- sort(rules, by="lift")
    inspect(rules.sorted)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check package `arules`.

**EDIT 1:**

If I understand you well, wouldn't this be enough?

```
> with(dat,summary(dat[percentage>=0.70,]))

     birds          wolfs          snakes      percentage   
 Min.   :5.00   Min.   :2.00   Min.   :2.0   Min.   :0.740  
 1st Qu.:5.25   1st Qu.:2.25   1st Qu.:2.5   1st Qu.:0.755  
 Median :5.50   Median :2.50   Median :3.0   Median :0.770  
 Mean   :5.50   Mean   :2.50   Mean   :3.0   Mean   :0.770  
 3rd Qu.:5.75   3rd Qu.:2.75   3rd Qu.:3.5   3rd Qu.:0.785  
 Max.   :6.00   Max.   :3.00   Max.   :4.0   Max.   :0.800
```

From the summary, you can read the range of values compatible with the chosen values of `percentage` (what you call best is not clear to me: you claim that you would want to have `1<wolfs<=3` and yet I can only find `2 =< wolfs` in your data example with percentage >= 0.70).

Comment: thank you F.Tusell, Is there any code example that you can share?

Comment: The package has a well written vignette with many examples that you can draw on.

Comment: I tried the arules package as but it requires that all variables will be factors and I have mixed dataset of factor,logical and continuous variables.Also I need that the value of "percentage" will be >=0.7 so in this case the outcome should be something like:  birds >=5,1<wolfs<=3 , 2<=snakes <=4 and I can't find a way to do It with arules

Comment: OK, look at EDIT1 in the answer.

Comment: If variables (wolfs, snakes, etc.) are defined as factors instead of as numerical, summary will give counts of each category instead of Min/Median/Mean/Max and quartiles. I do not understand what you mean by significance level here. What is the null hypothesis anyway?

Comment: My concern in regards to "EDIT1" is:what happens If you have very few cases that are far from the majority of values of a Independent variable - In this case the range will be very wide, so this could be a big problem. I think that "association rules" can be good If there is a way to add continuous variables, Or perhaps even to get a list of decision tree results in a way that be overviewed without the "tree graphics" would be good enough.As for the null hypothesis is that there is no relation between the dependent variable and the Independent variables.